# VLookup de fechas en macros de 2 libros diferentes

Tags: excel, vba, macros

comunidad.
Estoy realizando la búsqueda de fechas de otro libro donde presenta una condicional donde te indique "SI" si es feriado; caso contrario, "NO". Esto fue lo que realicé

```
Sub feriado()

Dim ultlinea As Long
Dim feriado As Variant
Dim id3 As Date
Dim cont As Long
Dim rango As Variant
Dim FeriadoX, libroactual As Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set libroactual = ThisWorkbook
Set FeriadoX = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\CRISTIAN\...\Feriados Calendarios.xlsx")
libroactual.Activate
    
ultlinea = Sheets("Prueba").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 
Set rango = FeriadoX.Sheets("Hoja1").Range("A1:A23")
    
For cont = 2 To ultlinea
    id = Sheets("Prueba").Cells(cont, 2)
    feriado = Application.Match(id3, rango, 0)
    
If Not IsError(feriado) Then
    Sheets("Prueba").Cells(cont, 15) = "SI"
Else
    Sheets("Prueba").Cells(cont, 15) = "NO"
End If
       
Next cont

FeriadoX.Close savechanges:=False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

El problema es que cuando corro la macro, las fechas que deberían ser Feriados según el otro libro que se tiene como referencia (Matriz_tabla) salen con "SI" y "NO" , y lo mismo pasa con los que no son Feriados. o sea no lee bien las fechas. Cabe recalcar que los rangos que se desea comparar están en formato Fecha en los Libros correspondientes.

Les adjunto el resultado del Excel y los resultados. La idea es que salga asi con los "SI" y los "NO" pero debidamente elegidos por la función Vlookup.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quizás me falta agregar alguna línea de código que me ayude a jalar la información del otro libro de manera adecuada.

Gracias!

Comment: ¿Por qué con VBA y no directamente una fórmula en Excel?

Answer (score 0):

Yo creo que podrías mejor hacerlo con COUNTIF porque VLOOKUP devolverá error si no encuentra el valor buscado.

Tu bucle FOR se podría quedar en:

```
For cont = 2 To ultlinea
    ID = Sheets("Prueba").Cells(cont, 2)
    
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rango, ID) > 0 Then
        Sheets("Prueba").Cells(cont, 15) = "SI"
    Else
        Sheets("Prueba").Cells(cont, 15) = "NO"
    End If
    
Next cont
```